# mingw64 not installed properly using msys2

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to install ming_w64 using msys2. I used the following command to install it:

`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

After installing compiling gives the following error:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
g++.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

After reinstalling ming_w64 this is shown:

```
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
(19/19) checking keys in keyring                                 [##################################] 100%
(19/19) checking package integrity                               [##################################] 100%
(19/19) loading package files                                    [##################################] 100%
(19/19) checking for file conflicts                              [##################################] 100%
(19/19) checking available disk space                            [##################################] 100%
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1.exe
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1plus.exe
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto1.exe
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/gnat1.exe
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/f951.exe
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1obj.exe
warning: could not get file information for mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1objplus.exe
```

Even after reinstalling I am unable to find cc1plus.exe in mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus running? Try disabling it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks a lot. I dont know why Windows Defender would delete those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) I solved it.
It was Windows Defender which was deleting those files. Excluding that folder fixed it.